# Traefik how to route from a backend service xteve with a port and path in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, proxy, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm trying to run a reverse proxy for xTeVe in docker using Traefik 2.6.3, however I'm getting stuck with using some of the middlewares.

By default xTeVe listens on port 34400 to connect to the DVR IP:

```
IP:                 192.168.96.2:34400
```

It also has a /web path for the the web UI:

```
web Interface:          http://192.168.96.2:34400/web/
```

If I just use `` "traefik.http.routers.xteve.rule=Host(`MY_HOSTNAME`)" `` then actually I can access it easily via the webui using `https://MY_HOSTNAME` which then redirects to `https://MY_HOSTNAME/web`.

I'm trying to do a reverse proxy on another service which actually has the same prefix as `/web` in it's service, so there is a conflict. This is why I wanted to remove `/web` from xTeVe and replace that with `/xteve`.

I can't seem to get that working at all. If I do a replacement to `/xteve` I can successfully connect to the service which is equivalent of connecting to the IP **not** the web Interface as I described above. So I'm really not sure why I can't connect to the web interface, I did try `/xteve/web` but that still doesn't give the web ui back, just the same webpage as `/xteve` would.

I've tried stripping the prefix, replacing the prefix, regex replace, using `Path` and `PathPrefix` but still no luck, see comments below:

```
 labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.xteve.rule=Host(`MY_HOSTNAME`)"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.xteve.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.xteve.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.services.xteve.loadbalancer.server.port=34400"
 #      - "traefik.http.middlewares.xteve-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/web"
 #      - "traefik.http.middlewares.xteve-addprefix.addprefix.prefix=/xteve"
 #      - "traefik.http.routers.xteve.middlewares=xteve-stripprefix"
 #      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.regex=^http://192.168.96.2:34400/web/"
 #      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.replacement=https://MY_HOSTNAME/xteve"
 #      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.regex=^/web/(.*)"
 #      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.replacement=/xteve/$$1"
```

I'm clearly missing something, but not sure what and looking for some help. The docs aren't really that clear and I seem to only find things that are for Traefik v1.

I'd be grateful if anyone can assist - thanks.

Edit:
I guess my real question is, how do I change a backend service from `<IP>:<PORT>/<PATH>` to `<FQDN>/<NEW_PATH>` in traefik.